# Running javascript in Content Page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, master-pages

In my ASP.Net 2008 app I've got a page that uses a Master Page and I want to use jquery/javascript but I can't even get this simple code to work.
the page loads and controls display but no alert.

Ideas?

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="cphMain" runat="server" ID="mainBodyContent">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery-1.4.1.js">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("Hey");          

    });
 </script>
 ....
other controls
...
```

Comment: Did you check if the browser reports any errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either have the `src` attribute set of  the script element *or* have it contain script in its body. Not both in the same time.

Comment: this works
<script src="../../js/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            alert("Hey");   
        });